# How to differentiate between two methods in MethodCallExpr in a method?

Tags: java, javaparser

```
public class A{
    void methodA(){
        add(1, 2);
        add(1.2, 2.5);
    }

    void add(int a, int b){
        // add two integers
    }

    void add(double a, double b){
        // add two double numbers
    }
}
```

Now I have used below code to extract method call inside a method

```
   new VoidVisitorAdapter<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void visit(MethodCallExpr n, Object arg) {
            super.visit(n, arg);

            System.out.println(n.getNameAsString());
        }
    }.visit(JavaParser.parse(code), null);
```

Now here how can I differentiate those two method call **add(1, 2)** and **add(1.2, 2.5)** inside **methodA** using **MethodCallExpr** ?

Comment: You do not need to.  Type of your actual parameters will determine the exact method.  This is the whole purpose of [method overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: I just wanted to know how can I differentiate those two methodcall using MethodCallExpr inside another mehtod @PM77-1

Comment: So the actual question is: How to specify parameter type?, right?

Comment: How to give two methods different signature so that I can identify those two methods as different when extracting from method calls? @PM77-1

Comment: getTypeArgs maybe http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/2.5.1/com/github/javaparser/ast/expr/MethodCallExpr.html#getTypeArgs--

Answer (score 1):

You can if you use the symbol resolution features. Once you have configured symbol resolution you can simply call `resolveInvokedMethod` and you will get an instance of `ResolvedMethodDeclaration`. On that object you can call `getQualifiedSignature()` or examine the parameters if you prefer.

To learn how to configure the symbol resolution please refer to the documentation.

Note: I am a JavaParser contributor

Comment: I just wanted to know after method calls using MethodCallExpr how can I know which method it is?

Comment: This is what I tried to answer to :) When you get the full signature you can easy distinguish the two methods from it. Or you can look into the type of parameters in the ResolvedMethodDeclaration. What is not clear?